# I can't get the output I want from the function. The output I get is NoneType

Tags: python, function

The essence of the code is as follows - in the input, we have two parameters (product and weight), in the output we must get equivalent values: "Proteins", "Fats", "Carbohydrates" and "Calories" relatives to the weight of the product. In addition to the function, we calculate the sum of values ("Proteins", "Fats", "Carbohydrates" and "Calories"). I get NoneType when I output the values "Proteins", "Fats", "Carbohydrates" and "Calories" from the function when I want to get a list. I tried to declare the list "output" and add values "Proteins", "Fats", "Carbohydrates", and "Calories" to it, but I also get NoneType in the output.
Here is a code:

```py
totalProteins, totalFat, totalCarbohydrates, totalCalories = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
listData = {}


def dietCalculator(product, weight):
    if weight == "info":
        if product in listData:
            return listData[product]
        else:
            print("No info")
            data = input("Type values: ").split(" ")
            listData[product] = float(data[0]), float(data[1]), float(data[2]), float(data[3])
            print(listData[product])
    elif weight == "add":
        data = input("Type values: ").split(" ")
        listData[product] = float(data[0]), float(data[1]), float(data[2]), float(data[3])
        print(listData[product])
    else:
        proteins = listData[product][0] * int(weight) / 100
        fats = listData[product][1] * int(weight) / 100
        carbohydrates = listData[product][2] * int(weight) / 100
        calories = listData[product][3] * int(weight) / 100
        return [proteins, fats, carbohydrates, calories]


while True:
    if input("Continue? ") != "No":
        inputs = input("Type product: ").split(" ")
        values = dietCalculator(inputs[0], inputs[1])
        totalProteins += values[0]
        totalFat += values[1]
        totalCarbohydrates += values[2]
        totalCalories += values[3]
    else:
        print("Total values for your meal: Proteins ", totalProteins, "Fat ", totalFat, "Carbohydrates ", totalCarbohydrates, "Calories ", totalCalories)
        break
```

Here is the error:

> totalProteins += values[0]
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

When I said, that i tried to declare the list "output" I changed:
`return [proteins, fats, carbohydrates, calories]`
to this:`output = [] output.extend((proteins, fats, carbohydrateds, calories)) return output` 
And that didnt solve my problem

Comment: Some of your `elif` branches don't have a `return` statement.

Comment: It looks like your indentation didn't get copied correctly.

Comment: Looks like your code lost some formatting along the way, but even so I can see paths that do not have a `return` in them and thus implicitly return `None`

Comment: Now I edited and copied code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `while True` branches. When the program is running and our input is, for example `egg add` our function, called dietCalculator, asks us to input 4 values for it

```py
elif weight == "add":
        data = input("Type values: ").split(" ")
        listData[product] = float(data[0]), float(data[1]), float(data[2]), float(data[3])
        print(listData[product])
```

, to add this into dict. And at this point nothing came out of these brackets, there wasn't any `return`. Thereby there wasn't any inference from function, so, that`s why

```py
values = dietCalculator(inputs[0], inputs[1])
totalProteins += values[0]
totalFat += values[1]
totalCarbohydrates += values[2]
totalCalories += values[3]
```

Line `totalProteins += values[0]` couldn't work, because there is no data to work with (no inference from function, as I said)

Attaching working code

```py
totalProteins, totalFat, totalCarbohydrates, totalCalories = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
listData = {}


def dietCalculator(product, weight):
    if weight == "info":
        if product in listData:
            return listData[product]
        else:
            print("No info")
            data = input("Type values: ").split(" ")
            listData[product] = float(data[0]), float(data[1]), float(data[2]), float(data[3])
            print(listData[product])
    elif weight == "add":
        data = input("Type values: ").split(" ")
        listData[product] = float(data[0]), float(data[1]), float(data[2]), float(data[3])
        print("Now values for", product, "are: Protein", listData[product][0], "Fats", listData[product][1], "Carbohydrates", listData[product][2], "Calories", listData[product][3])
    else:
        proteins = listData[product][0] * int(weight) / 100
        fats = listData[product][1] * int(weight) / 100
        carbohydrates = listData[product][2] * int(weight) / 100
        calories = listData[product][3] * int(weight) / 100
        return [proteins, fats, carbohydrates, calories]


while True:
    if input("Continue? ") != "No":
        inputs = input("Type product: ").split(" ")
        if not inputs[1].isdigit():
            print(dietCalculator(inputs[0], inputs[1]))
        else:
            values = dietCalculator(inputs[0], inputs[1])
            print("Values for this product are: Protein", values[0], "Fats", values[1], "Carbohydrates", values[2], "Calories", values[3])
            totalProteins += values[0]
            totalFat += values[1]
            totalCarbohydrates += values[2]
            totalCalories += values[3]
    else:
        print("Total values for your meal: Proteins ", totalProteins, "Fat ", totalFat, "Carbohydrates ", totalCarbohydrates, "Calories ", totalCalories)
        break
```